# .NET project for TCP messaging

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp

Is there an open source project or framework in .NET which provides the basic "plumbing" for messaging between client(s) and server over TCP? It seems like one of those things where I end up writing essentially the same thing over and over, and I'd like to abstract myself away from that a little bit more and deal with the particulars of my app, instead of writing *yet another* half-assed mechanism for messaging over TCP.

Hopefully something smaller/simpler than WCF. I'm really interested in something lightweight that doesn't try to solve every problem.

Comment: To the extent that WCF tries to "solve every problem", are you certain that it does not also solve your problem? Have you looked at using the net.tcp bindings and binary serialization?

Comment: WCF is indeed a beast. Saying that, there are plenty of introductory tutorials out there, many focusing on simple tasks such as the one you are attempting - this actually isn't *that* difficult in WCF as long as you don't want to do some fancy configuration or the server/client communication has certain pecularities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one you'll have issues with different activation, threading models, buffers, framing, security and serialisation at the least, in integration or hand-rolled code. It is typical of any UDP/TCP or config/attribute work in any language or environment.. And it will still need tweaking according to server or client needs, simple the nature of vast possibilities in I/O work.

Completely agree WCF is way too bloated and much slower in comparison to .NET Remoting (which is slower than managed socket code which is again much slower than native iocp code) to hand rolled code.. But it is extra work and if you managed the above in a general generics library (not more powerful templates which makes it harder in .NET, ie. you have to design types in odd ways + it is imperative to use interface) than you've done well over say a man-year with some sophisticated plumbing a la message-queuing (it is isn't impossible but imho and retrospect never worth doing 'generically'..).

Alternatives are MSMQ, something MS is increasingly betting more of its software on, or half-assed open source bits that just never satisfy the model you require completely. Tibcos, ActiveMQs, you name it. Even going lower level, the best of all is widely considered to be C++ boost::asio, and although considered top, like all out things out there it isn't appropriate for everything. And it is a pretty remarkable design so I'd watch out for a potential time-wasting exercise..

On .NET I'd first adopt whatever 50-thread service MS is pushing 'today', and if not do the 'yet again similar code' and look for similar concepts to equip your toolset down the line when it reappears (like every new I/O lib or framework does every 5 years or so).

Answer (score 3):

[WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163447.aspx) has a lot of the nuts and bolts built in. Though I haven't actually tried to implement it myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you need more than just simple messaging support, have a look at [.Net's remoting support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the Indy.net project.

It was originally written in Delphi, but that is what it is supposed to do.